# Converting a modem+router to a router (or access point) only

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

On my home network my main modem+router is a Huawei and my Internet connection is VDSL (not ADSL), but I need to convert the modem+router to a router only. Internet works fine on this (>15mbps actual download speed).

However, I need a strong signal on another floor, so I've installed a Cat 6 wire that runs from the Huawei modem+router to that floor. Now from my earlier internet connection, I have a Beetel 450TC3 modem+router which I want to use as an access point on the other floor and create a separate Wi-Fi SSID/password.

My internet provider tells me it is absolutely possible to turn off the modem functionality of the Beetel machine, but refrains from telling me how as it is not in their mandate. When I connect the Beetel machine with the previously mentioned Cat 6 cable, I am unable to access the configuration page. Ipconfig gives me the default gateway of the Huawei machine. I don't want to buy a new router if this issue can be solved.

Comment: You would need too configure the devices separately, with only one turned on at a time. They could be attempting to share the same gateway address, likely 192.168.1.1 or something similar.